# Switch by type of generic parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I would like to switch the type of generic parameter and <s>I have found one way to do it that works and pass the test</s> (*1) (Edited: this approach doesn't work for `string`, check `@dbc`'s comment):

```cs
public static string HelpWithThis<T>(this DummyClass<T> _)
    =>
    (T)default! switch // <- Code smell (in my opinion)
    {
        DateOnly => "This day",
        TimeOnly => "This hour",
        int or float => "This number",
        _ => "This",
    };
```

However, I am not fond of using type casting for `default!`.

Could someone kindly guide me on how to rewrite this function in a more elegant syntax?

**Test**

(*1) I paste here the whole test and instructions to reproduce:

```bash
dotnet new xunit -o gentyp
cd gentyp
dotnet add package FluentAssertions
```

```cs
// UnitTest1.cs
using FluentAssertions;
namespace gentyp;

public class DummyClass<T>{}
public static class DummyExtensions
{
    public static string HelpWithThis<T>(this DummyClass<T> _)
        =>
        (T)default! switch
        {
            DateOnly => "This day",
            TimeOnly => "This hour",
            int or float => "This number",
            _ => "This",
        };    
}

public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
        =>
        new DummyClass<int>()
        .HelpWithThis()
        .Should()
        .Be("This number");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the whole purpose of a generic function?

Comment: @Fildor, maybe. This is just a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but, please, be free to explain how to refactor to avoid anti-patterns.

Comment: What is this test for? What kind of syntax is considered elegant to you?

Comment: Honestly, I am still scratching my head. First thought was some kind of visitor pattern.

Comment: I see a 'Needs details or clarity' close vote. Please, before vote to close, ask here for details. @shingo, for me, create a `default!` value and typecasting it to generic type is not elegant. I consider not elegant this expression: `(T)default!`. Looks ok for you? The test is to check that the expression works and to check the method still work if you rewrite their body.

Comment: You could switch on `typeof(T)` and put the concrete type check in a case guard: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QcZo56.  Or honestly just use an old time sequence of `if` statements: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q8pSsI.

Comment: The `needs details or clarity` is a better option than closing as out of scope. SO is for programming questions, code review questions go to `codereview.stackexchange.com`.  Whoever voted to close assumed there's more to the actual problem than what the question describes  - and I agree with whoever voted that way. This *could* be a good question for SO it the purpose of `HelpWithThis` was explained, or what the desired outcome is. I'd say the *function itself* is the smell, as it's trying to do the job of an attribute

Comment: You've told that, but I'm aware of what is elegant. You can't do much for a type parameter. And the question is not clear for me, this test only indicates that "This number" should be returned when the type parameter is int.

Comment: hi @dbc, thanks about your time and your code. Yes, that is a much more robust approach. I initially dismissed it because it's very verbose. But I think I should consider it and perhaps it's the solution. I don't like it because it applies the typeof over and over again.

Comment: There is a proposal for "switch on type" in Github dotnet/csharplang: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/356 but it's just that - a proposal.

Comment: Hi @MatthewWatson, thanks about this link. I guess, I really want this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, are software patterns out of stackoverflow scope? Can you point me to stackoverflow docs where explains this question is out of scope? I really don't want to write off-topic questions. Thanks.

Comment: @daniherrera - the problem with your current approach is that it only works when `T` is a value type.  You can't add `string => "This string",` because `(T)default!` will be `null`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pehxn4.

Comment: @daniherrera this isn't a question about software patterns, it's about a code smell and how it can be rewritten. This isn't even a pattern, it's an idiom. This is highly subjective and comes under the `opinion based` or `belongs on another site`. For example, I'd prefer `typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Description` or something similar. I'd look for a way to cache this if it's used frequently. Data binding already takes advantage of attributes. This would put the help attribute on the type it refers to

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks about your comment. I agree with you, but it's a pity I can't write `or` on `where` restrictions: `public static string HelpWithThis<T>(this DummyClass<T> _) where T: int or float`. Neither a default (I guess)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks about your time and to be kind to me. I guess this is an opinion based question because dotnet has not a solution for this c# pattern, did you see MatthewWatson's comment?

Comment: @dbc, thanks about to point `string => "This string"` to me.

Comment: It's not a pattern. There are *multiple* ways to solve the "problem", whatever it may be and I remember *another* one - the HelpProvider in Windows Forms and the entire Extender Provider feature. This allowed adding extra properties to GUI components, like the Help topic or Tooltip, without modifying the component itself

Comment: So what *is* the problem? What code needs that help string and how will it be displayed? The GUI framework/stack probably has a way to display tooltips/help, the way Winforms did. *That's* a pattern

Answer (score 3):

`T` is static (because generic type parameters are always resolved at compile time). So, it seems wrong to make a dynamic switch on a static type.

I think that a "no code smell" version would be to use overloaded methods. Overload resolution happens at compile time too, which makes this approach natural.

```cs
public static string HelpWithThis(this DummyClass<DateOnly> _) => "This day";
public static string HelpWithThis(this DummyClass<TimeOnly> _) => "This hour";
public static string HelpWithThis(this DummyClass<int> _) => "This number";
public static string HelpWithThis(this DummyClass<float> _) => "This number";
public static string HelpWithThis(this object _) => "This";
```

---

Another solution is to add a static property returning a `T` that you can switch on:

```cs
public class DummyClass<T>
{
    public static T Value => default;
}
```

Then you can switch like this:

```cs
public static string HelpWithThis<T>(this DummyClass<T> _)
    =>
    DummyClass<T>.Value switch
    {
        DateOnly => "This day",
        TimeOnly => "This hour",
        int or float => "This number",
        _ => "This",
    };
```

Note that this works because we are switching on value types whose `default` value is not `null`. If you want to expand it to reference types, write the property as follows instead and add the constraint `where T : new()`:

```cs
public static T Value { get; } = new();
```

---

But I really would like to know what kind of problem you are trying to solve here. Maybe someone can come up with a better solution if you give additional context info.

Comment: I guess the first approach is the way. Thanks about your time.

Comment: If only we had extension properties ...

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to overloaded methods you could go old-school and use a static lookup table to convert a type into a string:

```
static readonly Dictionary<Type, string> _lookup = new ()
{
    [typeof(DateOnly)]  = "This day",
    [typeof(TimeOnly)]  = "This time",
    [typeof(int)]       = "This number",
    [typeof(float)]     = "This number"
};

public static string HelpWithThis<T>(this DummyClass<T> _)
{
    return _lookup.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var result)
        ? result
        : "This";
}
```

I personally prefer your original solution (as long as it's not being used with large structs!) but you might prefer this.

Comment: My approach fails for `strings`, check dbc's comment and link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pehxn4 . This is better than main.